# How to proceed when object is not found?

Tags: excel, vba

I am searching for a blank cell in a table. Want to have a msg or run a command when there is no blank cell. I tried below versions but none of them worked

```
Sub Macro1() 
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").DataBodyRange.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    On Error GoTo Line1
Line1:
    MsgBox "no blank cell is found"
End Sub
```

and also this one

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").DataBodyRange.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    If Selection = "" Then
        MsgBox "no blank cell is found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to catch the error and check if `BlankCells` is `Nothing`.

```
Sub Macro1() 
    Dim BlankCells As Range
    On Error Resume Next 'supress all error messages until …Goto 0
    Set BlankCells = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0 'never forget to re-activate error reporting immedeately!

    If BlankCells Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "no blank cell is found"
    Else
        MsgBox BlankCells.Cells.Count & " blank cell(s) found"
    End If
End Sub
```

You might benefit from reading …

- [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).
- [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

No need for selects and selection, you could try:

```
Sub try()

On Error GoTo noblanks
  MsgBox ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabel1").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count & " blank cells are found"
  Exit Sub
noblanks:
MsgBox "no blank cell is found"

End Sub
```